# Can I get just Gothic 1 on Steam?

Tags: steam, gothic

Discovering the demo (so-called "Playable teaser") for a remake of Gothic, I got hit with nostalgia and wanted to play the original again. I went to [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/65540/Gothic_1/) and found...

That it's seemingly [only available in a bundle](https://store.steampowered.com/sub/6375/) with the other two Gothic games. Gotic 2 and 3 are both readily available for separate purchase and download, but if I want to play number 1, it looks like I have to buy *both* of the other two.

Is there some button I'm missing? Or is this the only way for me to once again be 13 years old and beat up bandits and orcs (or more likely be beaten up myself) through Steam? It's not a terrible amount of money, but it just seems extremely strange and a little unreasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems not from Steam directly (with the "N/A" price in the bundle overview, see screenshot), but [GoG](https://www.gog.com/game/gothic) lists just Gothic 1. There are also shady Steam Keys websites that have keys for sale for just Gothic 1

[image: Gothic bundle]

Comment: GoG also seems to have better support for ancient games, but that's just my anecdotal experience :)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Judging from their name, one would think that that is their schtick.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it is not possible to buy only the first part.